# Select multiple columns and slice columns at the same time with .loc method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Taking into account this Pandas DataFrame df:

```
  A   B   C   D   E   F
0
1
2
```

With .loc method I can select specific columns like this:

```
df.loc[:, ['A','B','E']]
```

Or I can slice some columns like:

```
df.loc[:,'B':'E']
```

My question is? Can this method allow to combine these two options? For example for selecting the first column and slice other columns? 
I have tried:

```
df.loc[:,['A','D':'F']]
```

for selecting columns A, D, E, F.

Which is the correct syntax?

Comment: as far as I know that can't be done with column names, but column positions are friendlier

Comment: `df.loc[:, ['A']].join(df.loc[:, 'D':'F'])`

Comment: @piRSquared that gives the desired output, but the original question is if there's a slicing syntax that allow for disjoint ranges, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot natively do this using labels with `loc`, but you can do so using positions and [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) + `iloc` (it's the closest workaround).

```
f = df.columns.get_loc
df.iloc[:, np.r_[f('A'), f('D'):f('F')]]
    A   D   E
0 NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
```

This is under the assumption that your column names are unique.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply do it using `join`

```
df[['A']].join(df.loc[:, 'D':'F'])
```

Output:

```
A   D   E   F
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `pd.concat` and `map` `slice`s

This is a generalized approach that should work as expected.

```
sublocs = [slice('A'), slice('D', 'F')]
loc = lambda s: df.loc[:, s]
pd.concat(map(loc, sublocs), axis=1)

   A  D  E  F
0  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1
```

---

#### Completely obnoxious variant

```
sublocs = [slice('A'), slice('D', 'F')]
pd.concat(map(df.T.loc.__getitem__, sublocs)).T
```